# malformed JSON string

Tags: xml, json, perl

I am calling from an xml file, I am basically just trying to get the data out of the xml file into json, this is what i have

```
my $url ="someURL"
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
$req->content_type('application/json');
my $json = new JSON;
my $request_json = $json->allow_blessed->encode($req);
$req->content($request_json);
my $lwp       = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response  = $lwp->request($req);
my $response_json = $response->content;
my $parsed    = $json->allow_nonref->utf8->relaxed->decode($response_json);
```

The last line gives the following response:

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "<mytag...")
```

Comment: Re "I am basically just trying to get the data out of the xml file into json", Nothing in your code has anything to do with XML???

Comment: Re "I am basically just trying to get the data out of the xml file into json". JSON is created a datastructure. You need to start by building the correct data structure. You must first start by deciding what the correct data structure is for the XML you have.

Comment: Why is this tagged `template-toolkit`? Is `someURL` an XML document? Why are you trying to JSON encode an `HTTP::Request` object?

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines of your code

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
$req->content_type('application/json');
```

That's fine. You have created an `HTTP::Request` object that makes a `GET` request to the URL, and you have set a header in that request that says that the *content* will be JSON data. All that is necessary now is to add that JSON data.

Now this is *very* odd

```
my $json = new JSON;
my $request_json = $json->allow_blessed->encode($req);
$req->content($request_json);
```

You have encoded the whole of the `HTTP::Request` object as JSON and set that as the object's content.

I hope you can see that that isn't the way it's supposed to work? An HTTP request isn't expected to send a copy of itself as the data content.

What you *should* be adding as content I can't tell as it's a property of the the site you're sending the request to. Normally it's a description of the query that you want to make, in this instance formulated as a JSON string.

If this doesn't help you enough then you must tell us much more about the site you're trying to query.

Comment: Re "That's fine", Not quite. Content-Type makes no sense for a GET request since GET requests can't have content.

Comment: @ikegami: Not true: it's certainly a very strange thing to do, but quite legitimate.

Comment: Legal, yes*. Correct, no. The request has no content, the server surely doesn't expect content unless it expects a POST (as I summarized earlier), and the OP probably meant to use the Accept header.

Comment: * -- Actually, RFC 2616 defines a Content-Type header, but forgot to actually list it as a valid header for any message, be it a request or response!

Answer (score 0):

> *I am basically just trying to get the data out of the xml file into json*

JSON is normally created a data structure made of arrays, hashes, strings and numbers. Once you have this, all you need to do is

```
my $json = encode_json($data);
```

So you need to build the correct data structure. Since you didn't tell us what that is, I presume you haven't even decided what it is yet. That's the first thing you must do.